# Access SQL join from other databases

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 3 access databases (.accdb files):

- db1.accdb has 'Table 1'
- db2.accdb has 'Table 2'
- db3.accdb is empty

I should write a query in db3 that make a join with Tables 1 and 2 and show results.

I already tried something like this but it doesn't work...

```
( SELECT * FROM  [table 1]  IN 'C:\files\db1.accdb' ) t1
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT * FROM  [table 2]  IN 'C:\files\db2.accdb' ) t2
ON
t1.field1 = t2.field1 and t1.field2 = t2.field2
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your query maintains a syntax error as the top level `SELECT` should not be in parentheses. Removing them will not suffice since the `IN` clause interferes with `FROM` clause.

To use one `SELECT` and treat each external database table as a local table, simply period qualify the external database paths in brackets, similar to what you would do in server level RDBMS (i.e., MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server) when querying across databases on same server. And yes, brackets should not contain quotes:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM [C:\files\db1.accdb].[table 1] t1
INNER JOIN [C:\files\db2.accdb].[table 2] t2
  ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field2 = t2.field2
```

Alternatively with backticks:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM `C:\files\db1.accdb`.`table 1` t1
INNER JOIN `C:\files\db2.accdb`.`table 2` t2
  ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field2 = t2.field2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the query to look like this:

```
select . . .
from ( SELECT * FROM [table 1] IN 'C:\files\db1.accdb' ) as t1 INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT * FROM [table 2] IN 'C:\files\db2.accdb' ) t2
     ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 and t1.field2 = t2.field2;
```

The `. . .` is for the columns that you want from each table.